# Chosen (by Harvest) : is it possible to allow element which are not in the list in a multiple select list?

Tags: select, multiple-select, jquery-chosen

I am using the wonderful Chosen plugin developed by Patrick Filler.

But I don't success to allow user to add an element which is not in the list on a multiple select list. I have the message "No results match "XXXX"".

If it's not clear : for example, if I have in my list the elements 1, 2 and 3 and the user type 4, I let him use the for even if it's not in the list. I use it in order not to oblige him to register the email of a user when he wants to send the email. He can search the email in the registered list, add an email to the list, or just write the email in the input without registered it in the list.

I can do that with the jquery ui autocomplete plugin. As I don't want to use the two, just to be coherent, is there a way to what I want with the Chosen plugin (without heavy work) ?

Thanks
Bastien

Answer (score 0):

Check this project on **Github** and let me know if it helps or not

**[Ajax Chosen](https://github.com/meltingice/ajax-chosen)**

And in order to add items to your binded list just combine **Chosen** and **[KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/)**. Use **KncokoutJs** when your data model's state changes, your UI updates automatically.

Check this tutorial out for simple **How TO**

Answer (score 0):

There are several forks of `Chosen` that allow adding options to the list. I use the 
[koenpunt fork](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/166), which is well-maintained. You'll find links to the other implementations in that issue.